# Creating a grid within a layer using ST_HexagonGrid with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, hexagonal-grid

I am attempting to use SQL to create hexagonal grid in PostreSQL 12.5, and am getting the dreaded 'you may need explicit type casts' error. The layer grid_bounds is a standard polygon layer with GCS of 3857.

Here's my first attempt:

```
SELECT g.i, g.j, ST_Union(g.geom) AS geom
FROM dem.grid_bounds AS b
 INNER JOIN ST_HexagonGrid(10000, b.geom) g 
 ON ST_Intersects(g.geom, b.geom)
WHERE b.name = 'Lower48'
GROUP BY g.i, g.j, g.geom
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT b.ogc_fid, hex.geom
FROM
    dem.grid_bounds b
    CROSS JOIN
    ST_HexagonGrid(100000, b.geom) AS hex
WHERE
    name = 'Lower48'
    AND
    ST_Intersects(b.geom, hex.geom)
```

The error message returned in both cases is:

```
    ERROR:  function st_hexagongrid(integer, geometry) does not exist
    LINE 16:     ST_HexagonGrid(100000, b.geom) AS hex
                          ^

    HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I also tried using `ST_Transform (e.g. ST_HexagonGrid(100000, ST_Transform(b.geom,3857))`, but received the exact same error. I'm almost surely missing something obvious.

Comment: Try `SELECT postgis_version();` to check you have PostGIS 3.1

Comment: You can also test `SELECT ST_HexagonGrid(10000, ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(10, 10, 11, 11, 4326), 3857))`

Comment: According the documentation, the signature of the ```HexagonGrid``` function is ```ST_HexagonGrid(float8 size, geometry bounds);```. The first parameter must be a float. The syntax ```ST_HexagonGrid(10000.0, b.geom)``` or ```ST_HexagonGrid(10000::float, b.geom)``` should be work (in other case show the @ThomasG77 comment).

Comment: In my case I needed to run `SELECT PostGIS_Extensions_Upgrade();` to upgrade postgis from 3.0.2 to 3.1.3 even after I had postgis 3.1 installed.

Comment: I checked and I do have a 3.0 version of POSTGIS. If I run the upgrade, it will modify the application, but not the data structures, if I understand this right. That means that any system tables, layers, etc that are stored using 3.0 specs might break when POSTGIS is updated. Any thoughts on this? Is this something I should be concerned with?